# arcpy search cursor not working

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.2, cursor

Im running my script in ArcGIS 10.2 and the dialog window says completed, but the empty fields in the 'SoilsType' row of the 'mSoils' Feature Class aren't getting populated with the values from the 'SoilsType' field from the 'mLanduse' Feature Class.

```
cur = arcpy.da.SearchCursor(mLanduse, lField)
for row in cur:
 cur2 = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(mSoils, sField)
 for row2 in cur2:
     if row2[0] == '' or row2[0] is None:
         row2[0] = lField
         cur2.updateRow(row2)
```

Comment: I think the problem is in your cursor statements, what version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: with arcpy.UpdateCursor(Soils, query) as cursor: - I don't see where Soils is defined.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but when you use the with...as cursor format, there's no need to del row, rows. They're automatically deleted at the end of the with block. Also, are you sure you have empty (not Null) SoilType values?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do with both your cursors.  You are defining a search cursor but are not looping through the rows object.  Can you edit your question and provide more background information what you are trying to do with the landuse and soils layers?

Comment: Perhaps research here and elsewhere on "arcpy cursor where clause field value empty".  I think the problem is with `query` and the syntax you are using there.

Comment: @ artwork21, I am using ArcGIS 10.2 as described in my question.

Comment: @recurvata, yes some fields are blank in the 'SoilsType' row of the 'Soils' Feature Class.

Comment: To test your query, open up the Select by Attribute dialog in ArcMap. Verify your query there to know that it will work in this process.  Also as @r.pankevicous pointed out, Soils is not defined as a variable.  I think you forgot to add ' ' around it in the UpdateCursor.  That will definitely cause a problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of going the python route, I would recommend using this sequence of geoprocessing tools:

1. Create new field in soil table called layer, and field calculate it with the value "soil"
2. Perform union on soil layer and land use (soil first input and land use second input)

The union process will help you deal with soil features that span multiple land use features.  This will bring over the other soil type value/field from the land use table into one table (*soil_landuse_union*)

3. Finally, select records in *soil_landuse_union* that have a value of "soil" in the layer field that do not have a soil type and populate the soil type field with the unioned land use soil type field/value

If you have to perform this operation frequently, you could create a model or python script using the geoprocessing tools/steps above.

Comment: the script is taking longer to work, ie scroll bar moving heaps in dialog window, but still no values being populated.

Comment: +1 Wrapping cursors in `with` statements is the preferred method for working with cursors.

Comment: Is that saying that mLanduse has the blank fields? Because the blank fields are in mSoils.

Comment: You want to perform the update on mSoils or mLanduse layer?

Comment: on mSoils layer artwork21

Comment: Are you wanting to select each soil feature within the land use feature, if soil feature soil field is blank than populate if with the intersected land use soil field value?

Comment: exactly, that's what I'm trying artwork21.

Comment: I do not think you need arcpy to do this, have you looked into doing a spatial join on the soil layer to the land use and then performing a field calculation on those soil records that are blank and populate the soil type field with the joined land use soil type field?

Comment: Can be achieved either way; http://support.esri.com/em/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/41940

Answer (score 2):

Change your exception handler to this:

```
# Return any errors   
except Exception as e:
  print(e)
  arcpy.AddMessage(arcpy.GetMessages())
```

Now open py file in IDLE and try to run. See what error you have.

ED|T: for row3 in row2: = you'll get a "row2 is undefined" error here in case you'll manage to get here :) First clean up syntax errors first and people here can help you to solve the issue.

Comment: I changed the exception handler as you suggested and run the script in IDLE, checked module and no syntax errors and no other errors.

Answer (score 0):

One of the primary problems is in the following line of code:

```
rows3 = mLanduse
```

Here you are trying to pass a feature class (`mLanduse`) into the attribute table, which cannot be done.  Instead, you need pass a integer, float, string etc.  Perhaps you meant to do the following:

```
rows3[0] = row[0]
```

Comment: When I run the script in ArcGIS, the dialog windows is saying "Executing SelectByLocation", succeeded at the 'time' and script complete. However, the blank values are not being populated in the 'Soils' Feature Class.

Comment: That's not where the script will fail--it is at the part I describe in the post.

Comment: I have updated my script with your answer and checked 'Soils' feature class and values still didn't come through.

Comment: You will need to provide some visual examples of your data and intended output so that we have some idea of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

You're making a big assumption with your SearchCursor/UpdateCursor pairing that the features from both match up exactly in order. That might be 'okay' for your data now, but it might not always be.

If the features match up spatially, which seems likely based on your question, then just use the Spatial Join tool: http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/spatial-join.htm